# Python Regex trying to find pattern that has two sets of optional characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python regex on a pattern that has two sets of optional characters that may or may not be there.  Below is what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
h becomes a when h is preceded by o but can also be preceded by a colon (:)
following the o and then maybe followed by f,y,r (f|y|r)
```

So this rule would be applied to the following patterns.

```
o:fh -> o:fa
ofh -> ofa
o:h -> o:a
oh -> oa
```

Below is what I'm trying.

```
re.sub(ur"o[(:|)][(f|y|r)]h", "o\1\2a", word);
```

I'm really struggling with the grouping and the two sets of optional characters `:` and `(f|y|r)` that may or may not be there.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If `h` becomes `a` then why is `h` in the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, you are trying to use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) inside of [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).  In  simplest form, it lists the characters that may be matched inside square brackets ( *matching any character from the list* )

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can simply use one group, following the characters you want to be optional with [`?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

```
>>> re.sub(ur'(o:?[yrf]?)h', ur'\1a', word)
```

Explanation:

```
(          # group and capture to \1:
  o        #   'o'
  :?       #   ':' (optional)
  [yrf]?   #   any character of: 'y', 'r', 'f' (optional)
)          # end of \1
h          # 'h'
```

You could use the [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module which supports variable-length lookbehind.

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.sub(r'(?<=o:?[yrf]?)h', 'a', word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex elements are made optional by following them with `?`, not by enclosing them in brackets.  The correct way (well, *a* correct way) to write your expression is:

```
re.sub(ur"o(:?[fyr]?)h", ur"o\1a", word)
```

Note that the replacement string has to be raw (`r" "`) so that the `\1` won't be interpreted as character 0x01.